# SVN Rename Folder in branch, Conflict

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

I have a branch in which a folder was renamed. Now i'm trying to merge changes from trunk to this branch, but the files modified in the trunk are still under the original folder name, so svn throws a tree conflict. How can i resolve this?

The folder was renamed using svn rename.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896355/handle-renames-in-parallel-branches

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a case where the merge will always give a tree conflict for the complete merge. A shortcut to avoid this conflict and merge the code is that, after merging the complete trunk to this branch ... *ignoring the tree conflict*, merge the individual folder(s).

Eg:

```
/trunk
  /FolderA
  /FolderB
  /FolderC

/branhes
  /Branch1
    /FolderA
    /FolderB
    /Renamed Folder (Previously Folder C)
```

1. Merge `/trunk` with `/branches/Branch1`
2. Merge `/trunk/FolderC` with `/branches/Branch1/Renamed Folder`

Cheers!!